# Currency pair change

Tags: finance, fx

You are long 500 USD on EUR/USD. It drops by 2 points, what is your position?
Now it goes up by 2 points, what's your new position?

I saw this question on glassdoor for a company's interview page.

I confused what a point refers to here - basis point or pip?

I took it as a change of 2% (0.02) and got 490 USD for 1st part and then 499.8 USD for 2nd

I also took it as a 2 basis points change ie.e change of 0.02% (0.0002) and then the position for the 1st part would be 499.9 USD  and then position on the 2nd part is 499.9998 USD

I think its quite trivial if its just a simple change without percentages as that means u end back at 500 USD.

Sorry if the question is deemed to be off topic, I'll close it

Comment: It's possible that some details were lost while posting the interview question on Glassdoor.  I too would interpret it as basis points rather than pips, keeping in mind the market convention to quote cable EUR, GBP, and a few others vs USD.

Comment: What I find confusing is that the position is you are still long 500 USD, but it is worth more EUR if EURUSD "drops". But they ask the "position" not "the value of the position". The whole question seems strangely worded. Maybe the answer is "if EURUSD is down 2% then you have made 2.04% on your position, as measured in EUR".

Comment: I dont know what a point is either. I'd be inclined to the say the positions is the same if it goes down and then up. But if its in % then it wont be.

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thanks, if we assume it to be 2 basis points, would my answer then be correct to say 499.9 USD for the 1st part and then 499.9998 USD for the 2nd part?